# Check a string for values that shouldn't belong

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a string that *could* contain any of these values `set @string = "a, b, c"`

I thought I could do this using AMPscript

```ampscript
if IndexOf(@string,'a') > 0 or IndexOf(@string,'b') > 0 or IndexOf(@string,'c') > 0 then 

   /* do nothing */

else

  RaiseError('Unknown value submitted',true)

endif
```

The idea being if my string contains, say, `"a, b, c, x"`, or anything other than `a` or `b` or `c` there would be an error and skip that record.

But it's not working and I have no idea why. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: It is possible indexOf is 1 based in AMPscript - I don't know - but in other cases such a function is usually 0 based, so a value is found when `indexOf(value) >= 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [regexmatch](https://ampscript.guide/regexmatch) function:

**Code**

```ampscript
%%[

set @pattern = "[^(a|b|c|,|\s)]+"
set @str = "a, b, c, x"
set @result = RegExMatch(@str, @pattern, 0)
output(concat("<br>result: ", @result))

]%%
```

**Output**

```
result: x
```

In your example:

```ampscript
%%[

set @pattern = "[^(a|b|c|,|\s)]+"
set @str = "a, b, c, x"
set @result = RegExMatch(@str, @pattern, 0)

if empty(@result) then 

   /* do nothing */

else

  RaiseError('Unknown value submitted',true)

endif

]%%
```

I used [this](https://regex101.com/r/O1XXul/2) to test the pattern.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Now what if in my pattern I wanted to use a word boundary, say ```@str = "dog, cat, bird"```? I know I need to use a word boundary but I dont know where \b belongs:

set ```@pattern = "[^(\bdog\b|\bcat\b|\bbird\b|,|\s)]+"```?